# Proper Importation of Foxit's WebPDF Engine Into React App

Tags: reactjs, import, create-react-app, pdf.js, foxit

Does anyone know of a streamlined way, or perhaps a hacky way, of integrating Foxit's WebPDF library into a React project with minimal setup?

The library can be found here: https://github.com/foxitsoftware/WebPDF.js/

The app I am working with was created with the 'create-react-app' script and I'm not keen on ejecting the scripts to modify webpack to make this work, but I'll do it if necessary.

The app currently uses pdfjs as its PDF rendering engine, and it has a lot of issues rendering larger, more complex PDFs. We're looking for an alternative, and every alternative we've seen thus far (react-pdf, pdf.js express, and etc) is built on pdfjs. They've all failed in our simulated mobile tests.

I've reached out to Foxit's support, and I haven't received an answer yet on how to integrate it properly into React.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: That project is 4 years inactive and has 31 stars. I don't think it's a good bet.

Comment: I'm working to integrate webpdf into react app, are you able to find something useful?? @BradySnuggs

Comment: I'm afraid not, @JayPatel. Best of luck.